# Is $U(b,a)U(a,b)=1$ for the ordered exponential?

Tags: calculus, operator-theory

Let $b>a$ be two real numbers.
The ordered exponential was defined to be

$U(b,a)=T\{\exp[\int_a^b dt'O(t')] \}$

for some operator $O$. The meaning of operator here basically meant $O(x)O(y)-O(y)O(x)\neq 0$, i.e. one could not simply switch them around easily.

Is it true that $U(b,a)U(a,b)=1$ for the ordered exponential?

(Notice that for $x>y$, $\frac{d}{dx}U(x,y)=O(x)U(x,y)$ but $\frac{d}{dy}U(y,x)=U(y,x)O(y)$, thus the simple argument one might recall through the "boundary condition" did not follow. From the Taylor expansion, the "even order" of $\int_a^b dt_n\int_a^{t_{n-1}} dt_{n-1}...O(t_n)...$ did not cancel out. Thus, the result of $U(b,a)U(a,b)$ did not appear to be trivial.)

Comment: What is this $T$ in $T\{\exp(\dots)\}$?

Comment: @user10354138 See ordered exponential.(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_exponential ) It's basically inserted some theta functions for $\int dt_n ...dt_1 O(t_n)...O(t_1) \theta(t_n-t_{n-1})\theta(t_{n-1}-t_{n-2}) ...\theta(t_2-t_1) $ to make sure the $O(t_n)$ on the left was "latter" than $O(t_{n-1})$ on the left, for all $n>1$.

Answer (score 0):

The derivatives of $U(a,b)$ are :
\begin{align}
\partial_a U(a,b) &= O(a) U(a,b) \\
\partial_b U(a,b) &= - U(a,b) O(b)
\end{align}

The first equation is the definition of $U(a,b)$. To derive the latter, notice that :
$$\partial_a ( \partial_b U(a,b) ) = \partial_b( O(a) U(a,b)) = O(a) \partial_b U(a,b)$$
and therefore:
$$ \partial_b U(a,b) = U(a,b) \left[ \partial_b U(a',b) |_{a' = b}\right]$$

Then, we have the integral equation : $U(a,b) = \mathbf 1+ \int_b^a O(a')U(a',b) {\rm{d}}a'$, which gives $\partial_b U(a',b) |_{a' = b} = - O(b)$.

Now, we are ready to compute :
\begin{align}
\partial_a (U(b,a) U(a,b)) &= \partial_a U(b,a) U(a,b) + U(b,a)\partial_a U(a,b)\\
&= U(b,a) [-O(a)+O(a)]U(a,b) \\
&= 0
\end{align}
and therefore :
$$U(b,a)U(a,b) = \mathbf 1$$

Comment: The first two line were correct. The $\partial_a (U(b,a) U(a,b))$ part, however, you need to specify if $b>a$ and if the condition for $U(b,a)$ still hold. If being consist with the notation of $a>b$ that was used during the derivation, then $\partial_a U(b,a)$ had not been proven. (In that case, it's of the form $-O(a) U^\dagger (b,a)$ for the anti hermitian operator. i.e. the ordering $T$ meant the $\pm O(a)$ would appear on the left hand side.)

Comment: I use $\partial_a U(a,b) = O(a)U(a,b)$ as a definition for both $a<b$ and $a>b$. Then the integral equation holds in both cases and so does the derivation of $\partial_b U(a,b) = -U(a,b)O(b)$

Comment: But $\partial_b U(b,a)=U(b,a) O(b)$ for $a>b$, there were two different differential equations involved, as mentioned in the OP. $\partial_aU(a,b)=O(a)U(a,b)$ was not a definition.